# getting a NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python

```
def compa9():
    a=int(input("enter the first number"))
    b=int(input("enter the second number"))

compa9()
if a==b:
    a==a
    b==b
    print("they are equal")
if a>b:
    a==a
    b==b
    print (a,"is bigger and") (b,"is smaller")
if a<b:
    a==a
    b==b
    print  (b,"is bigger and") (a,"is smaller")
```

I tried to write a program to find the which number is bigger or smaller in python but I am getting an error,what should I do?

Comment: What does `a==a` suppose to do?

Comment: `a` and `b` are never defined in global scope. They are local variables in `compat9`

Comment: What is the function for? You could just put it all in global scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 3):

The variables must have been declared within the function or not declared.

In case you have it declared inside the function, you should use "return", as in the following example:

```py
def function_exemple():
    a=int(input("enter the first number"))
    b=int(input("enter the second number"))
    return a,b

a,b = function_exemple()

if a==b:
    a==a
    b==b
    print("they are equal")
if a>b:
    a==a
    b==b
    print (a,"is bigger and") (b,"is smaller")
if a<b:
    a==a
    b==b
    print  (b,"is bigger and") (a,"is smaller")
```

Answer (score 2):

As the top comment indicates, defining a variable in a function does not make that variable accessible within the global scope. Here is one change to your function that results in the functionality that you seem to be expecting.

```
def compa9():
    a=int(input("enter the first number"))
    b=int(input("enter the second number"))

    if a==b:
        print("they are equal")
    if a>b:
        print(a,"is bigger and",b,"is smaller")
    if a<b:
        print(b,"is bigger and",a,"is smaller")

compa9()
```

Alternatively, I think it makes more sense to have `compa9` take in the numbers of interest as inputs. In other words, I think you should do the following instead:

```
def compa9(a,b):
    if a==b:
        print("they are equal")
    if a>b:
        print(a,"is bigger and",b,"is smaller")
    if a<b:
        print(b,"is bigger and",a,"is smaller")

a=int(input("enter the first number"))
b=int(input("enter the second number"))
compa9(a,b)
```